# Read a request in asp.net core 3.1 from Angular client side

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have a post request from Angular.

```
addEmployee(Name: string, Address: string, Salary: number, CreateDate: string) {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('content-type', 'application/json');
    const employee: EmployeeDataModel = { id: null, name: Name, address: Address, salary: Salary, createdate: CreateDate };
    alert(employee);
    this.http.post<{data: EmployeeDataModel}>(this.appuri + "api/employee", employee, {headers})
      .subscribe((responseData) => {
        employee.id = responseData.data.id;
        this.employees.push(employee);
        this.employeesUpdated.next([...this.employees]);
      });
  }
```

I can't read a request body in .net core backend.

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Employee>> AddEmployee([FromBody]Employee employee)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            dbContext.Employees.Add(employee);
            await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

            return CreatedAtAction("GetAllEmployees", new { id = employee.ID }, employee);
        }
```

And i also have this error message in ModelState:

```
The JSON value could not be converted to System.Int32. 
Path: $.id | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 10.
```

Can you help me please because i don't know what's wrong as i'm new to this.

Comment: You will need to pass a value as `Id` that is not null. E.g. `0` or another actual number. Your `Employee` model in your ASP.NET Core app requires the value to be an int, so you need to pass a valid number or the model validation will fail.

Comment: Thank you so much. It works now. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `id` property from your request body, or set it to 0. The value `null` cannot be parsed to an `int` by the serializer.

```
const employee: Partial<EmployeeDataModel> = { name: Name, address: Address, salary: Salary, createdate: CreateDate };
// OR
const employee: EmployeeDataModel = { id: 0, name: Name, address: Address, salary: Salary, createdate: CreateDate };
```

The `Partial<>` is only to make sure typescript won't scream at you for ommitting the `id` property.

Note that setting it to a value other than 0 will mean that your `DbContext` will try to insert that value into the database, and unless your column in the database is not using IDENTITY (or has IDENTITY INSERT turned on), you will get an error again.